# Setting-up automated backup in AWS through Jenkins

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins

I want to setup an automated backup process for my aws linux(amazon linux) machine with the help of Jenkins. Installed Jenkins in my server and created a Jenkins account and installed the backup plugins. Tried creating a backup job to test. Now I need to automate the backup job to take backups on another backup server periodically.